# Populate column with content from another column

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a table in postgres where one field (group_id) is missing for some older records. However, another field consist of urls and one part of the url is the group_id. The following substring extracts the group_id

```
"substring"(my_table.url, '.*app/([^/]*)'::text)
```

How do I replace the missing records with these?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE my_table SET group_id = "substring"(my_table.url, '.*app/([^/]*)'::text);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I solved my question at the same time as I was writing it =)

Comment: Actually, if your `UPDATE` is as simple as that, you could skip the table reference near `url` and also function `substring` does not need to be quoted. One more thing that Postgres does for you is implicit casting, so `::text` is not needed here 8)